# 時系列の値を線形補間し、別の時系列インデックスに変換する方法

Tags: python, pandas

concatとjoinメソッドを利用することで、DataFrameのインデックスを変換することができたのですが、
もっとスマートな方法ありますでしょうか？
（実際は、データの件数が増えることを前提としています。）
よろしくお願いします。

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# インデックスを変換する関数
def convert_index(df:pd.DataFrame, target_index:pd.DatetimeIndex=None)-> pd.DataFrame:
    if target_index is None:
        target_index = pd.date_range(start=df.index[0].floor('D'), end=df.index[-1].ceil('D'), freq='D')
        print(target_index)
    s = pd.Series(index=target_index, dtype=object, name='dummy')
    df = pd.concat([df, s], axis='columns') # インデックスを合成
    df = df.drop(columns=[s.name])
    df = df.interpolate(method='time', limit_direction='both') # 線形補間
    df = df.join(s, how='right') # target_indexを含む行を抽出
    df = df.drop(columns=[s.name])
    return df

# テスト用データ用意
df_in = pd.DataFrame(data={ 'value':[100, 200, 160] }, index=[
    pd.Timestamp('2021/12/01 01:00'),
    pd.Timestamp('2021/12/01 23:00'),
    pd.Timestamp('2021/12/03 16:00'),
])
df_out = convert_index(df_in)

display(df_in)
display(df_out)
# グラフ表示（結果確認用）
plt.scatter(x=df_in.index.to_list(), y=df_in['value']) # 点で表示
plt.plot(df_out) # 線で表示
plt.show()
```

Comment: 元々と変換後の時間間隔やデータ数の具体的な値を記述した方が的確な助言・回答が得られるでしょう。またおそらくデータ数はもっと多くしないと意味や効果が無いでしょうね。[pandasで時系列データをリサンプリングするresample, asfreq](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-time-series-resample-asfreq/), [DataFrameの時系列データのリサンプリング](https://docs.pyq.jp/python/pydata/pandas/resample.html), [Resample and Interpolate time series data](https://kanoki.org/2020/04/14/resample-and-interpolate-time-series-data/), [concate機能を利用した補間を行う際のエラーについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65438/26370)

Comment: ありがとうございます。resampleが利用できそうです。が、時刻が00:00以外のデータを補間してくれなかったので困っていました。resample関数については、別件にて、質問してみようかと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ありがとうございます。
「ate_range の頻度？を細かくして補間し, そこから求める頻度でリサンプリングする方法」
多分理解できました。解決できたと思います。
1.アップサンプルは、reindex+interpolate（もしくはresample）を利用する。
　interpolateで指定した単位より、細かい日時のレコードは線形補間の対象外となるので注意。
2.ダウンサンプルは、asfreqを利用する。
　asfreqはあくまで抽出なので、少なくとも等間隔のレコードが含まれている必要がある。
3.時系列のインデックスは、等間隔なインデックスに統一したほうが処理しやすい
　ある不揃いな（等間隔ではない）データの、インデックスに合わせるより、日ごと、時間ごとなどの等間隔なインデックスに変換（統一）したほうが処理しやすい。

```
def convert_index(df:pd.DataFrame)-> pd.DataFrame:
    target_index = pd.date_range(start=df.index.min().floor('D'),
                                    end=df.index.max().ceil('D'),
                                    freq='1h')
    df.index = df.index.floor('1h') # ←インデックスを1h単位で丸めて統一。こうしないと後のreindexで削除されてしまう。すべてのインデックスが上記pd.date_rangeに含まれているなら実行不要。
    df = df.groupby(level=0).mean() # ←丸め後（1h以内に）に、インデックスが重複しないなら、この行の実行は不要

    return (df.reindex(target_index)
              .interpolate(method='time', limit_direction='both')
              .asfreq('1D'))
```

以下のURLも参考になりました。
<https://ari23.hatenablog.com/entry/pandas-resample-asfreq>

Answer (score 1):

ありがとうございます。
インデックスのTimestampにミリ秒以下の値が含まれていると、線形補間の対象外となることが分かりました。
上段に期待結果、下段にreindexを利用したときの結果を添付いたします。
reindex便利そうですね。
値なしのSeriesオブジェクトを作成しconcatしたところがスマートではないですね。
使いこなせるようもう少し調べてみます。

[image: 期待する結果]

[image: reindexを利用したときの結果]

ファイル添付できないようなので、参考情報として、以下にin_data.csvの一部を記載いたします。

```
,value
2021-02-03 00:00:00+09:00,10000
2021-02-11 04:32:25.945945946+09:00,10330
2021-02-19 09:04:51.891891892+09:00,10660
2021-02-27 13:37:17.837837838+09:00,11000
2021-03-07 18:09:43.783783784+09:00,11330
2021-03-15 22:42:09.729729730+09:00,11660
2021-03-24 03:14:35.675675676+09:00,12000
2021-04-01 07:47:01.621621622+09:00,12330
2021-04-09 12:19:27.567567568+09:00,12660
```

Answer (score 0):

`date_range` の頻度？を細かくして補間し, そこから求める頻度でリサンプリングする方法

```py
def convert_index(df:pd.DataFrame, target_index:pd.DatetimeIndex=None)-> pd.DataFrame:
    if target_index is None:
        target_index = pd.date_range(start=df.index.min().floor('D'),
                                     end=df.index.max().ceil('D'),
                                     freq='1h')

    return (df.reindex(target_index)
              .interpolate(method='time', limit_direction='both')
              .asfreq('1D'))
```